# display a variable - Random

Tags: javascript, random, display

Good evening,

I have a bug after several tries I still can not find the solution :(

I would like to see a month click when you click again another month is displayed but not the same you remove it from the list

That's my code for the moment

Being very novice but looking on google I did not find an answer to my question

```js
function randomonth() {
var tbl="janvier,février,mars,avril,mai,juin,juillet,août,septembre,novembre,décembre".split',');
var randMois=[];

while (tbl.length) randMois.push(tbl.splice(Math.random()*tbl.length,1)[0]);
  document.getElementById("mois").innerHTML = tbl;

 }
```

```html
<button onclick="randommonth()">Try it</button>

<p id="mois"></p>
```

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: Now I know what the months are in French! Thanks!

Comment: All the pleasure is for me :p

Comment: Code snippet does not work...

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this:

```js
function randommonth() {
  var tbl="janvier,février,mars,avril,mai,juin,juillet,août,septembre,novembre,décembre".split(',');
  var mes = tbl[Math.floor(Math.random()*tbl.length)];
  document.getElementById('mois').innerHTML = mes;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="randommonth()">Try it</button>

<p id="mois"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast response but I can not display a month at the click of the button :(

Comment: Hang on... I'll see what I can do

Comment: Ok, vous n'êtes pas sûr d'avoir un mois différent à chaque fois, mais cela devrait fonctionner maintenant. (Merci, Google Traduction) :)))

Comment: Haha, thanks but if I want every month to go out only once how should I go :)
and yes haha thank you google translation it's for a homework it's pretty complicated I think: p

Answer (score 0):

To achieve, expected use below option of creating empty array to store month into it everytime and check everytime whether it is displayed already or not

```js
var tbl="janvier,février,mars,avril,mai,juin,juillet,août,septembre,novembre,décembre".split(',');
var randMois=[];

function randommonth() {
  var mois = tbl.splice(Math.random()*tbl.length,1)[0]; 
  console.log(randMois,mois)
  if(randMois.indexOf(mois)==-1 && randMois.length < tbl.length){
       randMois.push(mois)
       document.getElementById("mois").innerHTML = mois;
  }else{
      console.log("month already displayed",mois)
  }
 
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="randommonth()">Try it</button>

<p id="mois"></p>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Yayxzj?editors=1010